Calculate the year by horoscopes?
Does we can calculate year by using horoscope?
I have horoscope,The Lagna was fully aspecied by the benign planets like Guru. Mars, Sun and Saturn were exalted and Guru was at the zenith.
Can any one calculate year by using above horoscope

Year was 1719 CE, any date between Apr/11 and May/11, should be fine. Lagna was Scorpio (Vrichiga) because Jupiter occupies zenith (Leo Sign). At the same time, being at Zenith, Jupiter can't aspect Lagna, since it has 5th, 7th and 9th aspects only. However, only Mars can aspect Lagna from Zenith and no body else. Note that Sun, Saturn and Mars were all exalted on that range of dates. If you set Date of Birth around Apr/27/1719, then except Jupiter, other two benefics viz., Venus and Mercury being occupied at Taurus sign aspect lagna(Scorpio) with 7th aspect!

Date of birth may not lying on 5th century BCE ?

Why not? You search beyond 1719 CE backwards every 30 years (it takes around 30 years for Saturn to orbit around zodiac) and look for the year at which the Sun, Mars and Saturn were in exaltation along with Jupiter at zenith concurrently. You will arrive at few more such occasions until the beginning of CE. You may also search beyond CE into BCE you will definitely arrive at such years.

For instance, in the 5th century BCE, Mar/24/-491, arrived at a configuration where the Sun, Mars, and Saturn were all exalted and Jupiter was at zenith (aries sign) with Cancer Lagna. The problem is lagna was not aspected by benign planets such as Venus and Mercury. The configuration that matches your requirement is either Scorpio or Libra lagnas, then only lagna will be aspected by the two benefic (Venus and Mercury) barring Jupiter because he should be at zenith.

Let me try to arrive at your expected configuration beyond 5th century BCE.

Do you use Chitrapaksha Ayanāmsa?

No, we don’t use chitrapaksha ayanamsa

Then, what was the ayanāmsa did you use?
